# How do I debug a buildup in "page" memory in safari dev tools?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, webview, memory-leaks, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to debug a large memory leak I am seeing in a webview embedded in a unity app. Unfortunately, I am stuck using safari dev tools.

In the dev tools I see that my JS heap is staying steady, around 75mb. However, my "page" memory is growing quickly. Over the course of 10 minutes or so it grew from 272mb to up over 1gb.

I don't know how to tell what is taking up all that "page" memory. Is there a way I can see what is building up, similar to the javascript allocations timeline?

Comment: Are you using some recursive function?

Comment: I doubt someone will be able to help you with so little info. Best I can say is to try removing parts of the content from the page and narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something similar to JavaScript allocations timeline, you can do the exact thing in Safari following these steps

`Safari DevTools -> Memory tab -> Start Recording JavaScript Allocations`

Let the application run for a while; then stop the recording and check the timeline for any significant allocations

In addition, you can do a couple other checks as described below

`Safari DevTools -> Memory tab -> Start Recording Heap Allocations`

After a while, stop the recording and check the timeline for any significant allocations

`Safari DevTools -> Memory tab -> Record`

Again, stop the recording after a while, take a snapshot using the Take Heap Snapshot button and then compare multiple snapshots in order to identify objects that aren't being garbage collected.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding these instructions. Safari's dev tools don't have a Memory tab. This question was about what Safari reports as its "Page" memory usage, which it lists separately from "JavaScript" memory.

Comment: @JoshKelley I must have a custom version of Safari, just kidding... ;)
Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced tab, check the box next to 'Show Develop menu in menu bar'. Then 'right click' on your page -> Inspect Element -> Tmeline -> Memory

Comment: Okay. As I mentioned, though, this appears to give JavaScript memory usage, not what Safari calls "Page" memory usage.